# Wiping a Hard Disk while leaving a message behind

Tags: hard-drive, forensics

I wanted to know if there was a method to wipe a hard disk, so that if someone tried to recover data, they would be greeted by a message that the wiper chooses. For instance, in [this video](https://youtu.be/NG9Cg_vBKOg?t=3m55s) the wiper has wiped the disk in such a manner that forensics yielded an abusive phrase.

Also, from what little I know about forensics, I just use some application like Recuva to view deleted files. What application can I use to inspect the data, even if its just zeroes?

EDIT: I would also like to know the name of an application which could wipe the hard disk in such a manner.

Thanks

Comment: If I say yes its possible, is that enough, or are you actually looking for how to get this? If that's the case, this question might be too broad.

Comment: Yeah, I do want to know how to do it. The video source is trusted enough that it is possible

Comment: If you're happy leaving "them" a message, but it may encourage "them" to look harder... overwriting with zeros could look like a never-written area, or random data could look like corruption (or encryption, so maybe worse),  but I doubt it's ever a good idea to give the message "f*** you" to authority figures (employer, govt, etc) who could be investigating you. FYI `cat` & `tr` could output unlimited single characters (all the same character) to a hard drive

Comment: Overwriting the entire drive with zero's ensures no data can be recovered by anyone, then leave a text file on the hard drive with your message. If you want them to work for the message, shift delete the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dc3dd - http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Dc3dd, for example: dc3dd wipe=/dev/sdx tpat=foobar where /dev/sdx could be /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, etc. This would fill the drive with the text pattern foobar.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted ?